# Hiding a Dependency Property

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

Just wondering if this is a good practice or if it could cause any troubles in the long run. To be honest, I'm surprised it even works - it does the job, but I'm not sure if it's risky.

Basically we created a `NumericTextBox` that derives from `TextBox`, and we overrode the `Text` property with the `new` keyword to remove commas from the text:

```
public class NumericTextBox : TextBox
{
    public new string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Text.Replace(",", String.Empty);
        }
        set
        {
            base.Text = value;
        }
    }
}
```

What I don't like about it is that I know `Text` is a dependency property and we're overriding it, but surprisingly we can still bind to it in XAML:

```
<this:NumericTextBox x:Name="textBox"
                     Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=SomeText, Converter={StaticResource debugConverter}}" />
```

Then in C# when we call `textBox.Text` we do get the values without commas.

What do you guys think?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should [add your class as an owner of the dependency property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754002.aspx) and override the getter and setter there:

```
public class NumericTextBox : TextBox
{
    public NumericTextBox() { }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty NumericTextProperty = TextBox.TextProperty.AddOwner(typeof(NumericTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(null));
    public new string Text
    {
        get { return ((string)this.GetValue(NumericTextProperty )).Replace(",", String.Empty); }
        set { this.SetValue(NumericTextProperty , value); }
    }
}
```

You also have the possibility of [overriding the metadata of the dependency property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754209.aspx) to hook in a custom validation callback method.

You approach doesn't work, because WPF doesn't actually use the class properties to change the value, but the dependency property system. It simply calls the SetValue method as you do in your property setter. You can try it out by setting a breakpoint in the setter, and changing the bound property in the gui. The setter breakpoint will never be hit. But you can hook into the events provided by the dependency property metadata.

Comment: It complains about not using the 'new' keyword if hiding was intended, I tried adding it and I get an exception. Might now work for the Text property or something.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. But, is that a good practice, or should it be avoided? And if you know why, that would help a lot too.

Comment: Does that code run ok for you? Over here I get a run time exception: http://screencast.com/t/EbiYg14f